# Appending data to data-frame and saving to .csv but csv is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I am walking through a directory tree.  In each sub directory when I come across a file called `portfolio-insts-summary.csv` I open the file and read the contents of the .csv to a data-frame called `df`.  I then append the `df` data-frame to another data-frame called `final_df`.  Once the code has finished going through the directory tree the data-frame `df_final` is saved to a .cvs called `final.csv`.

I have printed the head of each `df` dataframe and they contain data, however when I write the `df_final` to a final.csv the .csv the file is created but is empty.  What have I done wrong and why is the `final.csv` file empty even though the `df` has data from each file?

The code is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jul 18 22:30:05 2018

@author: stacey
"""


import pandas as pd
import os

from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

def main():        

    folder = '/home/stacey/work/jp_aus_bk_tests/port_100k/'

    df_final = pd.DataFrame()

    for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in files:
            filename_without_extension, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if filename_without_extension == 'portfolio-insts-summary':

                df = pd.read_csv(dirname + '/' +filename)

                df_final.append(df)

    df_final.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    print ("Processing_Results...17/07/18")


    try:

        main()



    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

Comment: Didn't my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `DataFrame.append` returns a new Dataframe instead of modifying the original in place. ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)). If you change your code to `df_final = df_final.append(df)` it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes that is why I didn't spot that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add all the frames to an array and use `pd.concat` to combine them. I also needed to call `main()` before the last print.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def main():

    folder = './dir/'

    frames = []

    for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in files:
            filename_without_extension, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if filename_without_extension == 'portfolio-insts-summary':

                df = pd.read_csv(dirname + '/' +filename)
                frames.append(df)


    final = pd.concat(frames)
    final.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print ("Processing_Results...17/07/18")
```